Bishop gradient calculation
In section 3.1.1 of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher Bishop, it is written that
$$\ln p(\mathbf{t} | \mathbf{w}, \beta) = \frac{N}{2} \ln \beta - \frac{N}{2} \ln (2 \pi) - \beta E_D(\mathbf{w})$$
where $E_D(\mathbf{w}) = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N} \{ t_n - \mathbf{w}^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\phi}(\mathbf{x}_n) \}^2$
Then he says

The gradient of the log likelihood
function (3.11) takes the form
$$ \nabla \ln p(\mathbf{t} | \mathbf{w}, \beta) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N} \{ t_n - \mathbf{w}^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\phi}(\mathbf{x}_n) \} \boldsymbol{\phi}(\mathbf{x}_n)^\text{T}$$

I assume the gradient is being taken with respect to $\mathbf{w}$ then shouldn't the final result be of the same dimensions as $\mathbf{w}$ but $\boldsymbol{\phi}^\text{T}$ is not, so can somebody walk me through where my reasoning is wrong, I think the $\boldsymbol{\phi}^\text{T}$ should be $\boldsymbol{\phi}$.

Some authors represent the gradient as a column vector; others represent it as a row vector. You can take the transpose of the vector if you want to switch between conventions.

Start with the scalar function $\phi={\bf x}^\intercal {\bf x}$. The differential ${\sf d}{\phi}$ is a scalar and the differential ${\sf d}{\bf x}$ is a vector. From the definition of the derivative of $\phi$ w.r.t. to $\bf x$ we must have ${\sf d}\phi = D_{\bf x}\phi ; {\sf d}{\bf x}$ where $D_{\bf x}\phi$ stands for "the derivative of $\phi$ w.r.t. $\bf x$". Since ${\sf d}{\bf x}$ is a (column) vector, $D_{\bf x}\phi$ must be a transpose (row) vector so that $D_{\bf x}\phi ; {\sf d}{\bf x}$ returns a scalar. So we get $D_{\bf x}\phi={\bf x}^\intercal$.
